# Возможность менять кол-во просмотров элемента битрикс в админке

Tags: php, битрикс

Хелп, пытаюсь добавить поле SHOW_COUNTER в админку для редактирования, как тут:
https://nuka.ru/blog/bitriks-upravlyaem-kolichestvom-prosmotrov-elementa/

```
$tabControl->AddEditField("SHOW_COUNTER", GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_SHOW_COUNTER").":", $arIBlock["FIELDS"]["SHOW_COUNTER"]["IS_REQUIRED"] === "Y", array("size" => 7, "maxlength" => 10), $str_SHOW_COUNTER);
```

Или как тут:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5258

```
$tabControl->BeginCustomField(
   "SHOW_COUNTER",
   GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_SHOW_COUNTER"),
   $arIBlock["FIELDS"]["SHOW_COUNTER"]["IS_REQUIRED"] === "Y"
);
?>
<tr id="tr_SHOW_COUNTER">
   <td><? echo $tabControl->GetCustomLabelHTML() ?>:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="SHOW_COUNTER" id="SHOW_COUNTER" size="7" maxlength="10" value="<?= $str_SHOW_COUNTER; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?
$tabControl->EndCustomField("SHOW_COUNTER", '<input type="hidden" id="SHOW_COUNTER" name="SHOW_COUNTER" value="' . $str_SHOW_COUNTER . '">');
```

Ничего не выводится, кучу времени уже убил, вроде всё нормально работает с другими полями кроме SHOW_COUNTER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал таким образом, лютый костыль, мне за него стыдно, но если как в документации как обычно не работает и нет вагона лишнего времени, то вот вариант:

Делаем всё как тут: https://nuka.ru/blog/bitriks-upravlyaem-kolichestvom-prosmotrov-elementa/
Но само поле вставляем по другому:
С помощью JS в самом конце документа:

```
//////////////////////////
//END of the custom form
//////////////////////////
echo '<script>
trSort = document.getElementById("tr_SORT");
trSort.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<tr id=\"tr_SORT\"><td width=\"40%\" class=\"adm-detail-content-cell-l\">' . GetMessage("
IBLOCK_FIELD_SHOW_COUNTER ") . ':</td><td class=\"adm-detail-content-cell-r\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"SHOW_COUNTER\" value=\"' . $str_SHOW_COUNTER . '\" size=\"7\" maxlength=\"10\"></td></tr>");
</script>';
```